# How to have multiple Textboxes travel in random directions with specific time interval between them?

Tags: java, animation, javafx, javafx-8, game-development

I am currently making a type speed game using JavaFX where words should fall from the top and the user has to type them as fast as they can before the fall to the bottom. I have the basic set up of the game ready. The only thing I am struggling with is how to get the words to fall from the top and go to the bottom (currently they travel from bottom to top). And also I want multiple words to fall down from random location at the top (not the same point of origin) at specific time interval between them, say 30 milliseconds. The code I have so far:

```
public void showWords() throws InterruptedException
    {
        int missedWords = 0;        // number of words the user failed to type
        while (missedWords != 10)   
        {
            dequedWord = queue.dequeue();           // the word that the Text object will contain
            Text runWord = new Text(dequedWord);

            wordsPane.getChildren().add(runWord);   // the canvas in which the words will travel from top to bottom
            double PaneHeight = wordsPane.getHeight();
            //double PaneWidth = wordsPane.getWidth();
            double runWordWidth = runWord.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();

            KeyValue initKeyValue = new KeyValue(runWord.translateYProperty(), PaneHeight);
            KeyFrame initFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, initKeyValue);

            KeyValue endKeyValue = new KeyValue(runWord.translateYProperty(), -1.0 * runWordWidth);
            KeyFrame endFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(12), endKeyValue);

            Timeline timeline = new Timeline(initFrame, endFrame);

            timeline.setCycleCount(1);
            timeline.play();

            // add code to check whether user typed the word in the Text object

            missedWords++;
        }
    }
```

I am new to animation so I do not know much about Timeline, KeyValue and KeyFrame classes. I tried reading the documentation for the APIs, but did not help me much. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The y axis of the coordinate system points **down** (which is quite common in computer graphics). This is why your nodes move in the wrong direction. Furthermore `Timeline` does not seem to be well suited here, since you'd need to run a `Timeline` per word and another `Timeline` for adding new words.

I recommend using a `AnimationTimer` instead which contains a method called for every frame which allows you to update the positions, remove old words and add new words depending on the time.

Example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final Queue<String> words = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(
            "Hello",
            "World",
            "foo",
            "bar"
    ));
    final Pane wordsPane = new Pane();
    wordsPane.setPrefSize(800, 400);
    final long wordDelay = 500_000_000L; // 500 ms
    final long fallDuration = 12_000_000_000L; // 12 s

    AnimationTimer animation = new AnimationTimer() {

        private long lastWordAdd = Long.MIN_VALUE; // never added a word before
        private final Map<Text, Long> nodes = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        private double nextX = 0;

        private void assignXPosition(Text text) {
            text.setTranslateX(nextX);
            nextX += text.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth();
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            // updates & cleanup
            long deletionLimit = now - fallDuration;
            for (Iterator<Map.Entry<Text, Long>> iter = nodes.entrySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                Map.Entry<Text, Long> entry = iter.next();
                final Text text = entry.getKey();
                final long startTime = entry.getValue();
                if (startTime < deletionLimit) {
                    // delete old word
                    iter.remove();
                    wordsPane.getChildren().remove(text);
                } else {
                    // update existing word
                    double factor = ((double) (now - startTime)) / fallDuration;
                    Bounds bounds = text.getBoundsInLocal();
                    text.setTranslateY((wordsPane.getHeight() + bounds.getHeight()) * factor - bounds.getMaxY());
                }
            }

            if (words.isEmpty()) {
                if (nodes.isEmpty()) {
                    stop(); // end animation since there are no more words
                }
            } else if (lastWordAdd + wordDelay <= now) {
                lastWordAdd = now;
                // add new word
                Text text = new Text(words.remove());
                wordsPane.getChildren().add(text);
                assignXPosition(text);
                text.setTranslateY(-text.getBoundsInLocal().getMaxY());
                nodes.put(text, now);
            }

        }
    };
    animation.start();

    Scene scene = new Scene(wordsPane);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Hey @fabian, thank you for your response. I tried implementing this code in my program, now no words are showing up at all and I'm not sure why. When I go over the code, it is doing what it is supposed to do, but when I run the program and click the "start" button, no words fall from the top. Any ideas?

Comment: @mdave1701 not really. I tested this and for me it works flawlessly. The fact that you didn't find any issue when debugging doesn't shed any light on the issue either. Debugging the `handle` method will likely lead to the delay between the frames being quite long and probably the nodes exit the screen within 2 frames...

Comment: I made a new project, implemented this code and it's working great. Perhaps the problem was somehow using this method as a setOnMouseClicked() event handler? I had a button called "start" and I used this code as event handler for that button. So my guess is it probably had problems with that.